# Copy/Paste APA-style Text References into Word as Dynamic Citations for Automatic Bibliography

Tags: ms-word, reference, ms-office

I've got a huge existing literature review (> 200 pages) in my thesis. However, I still need to add the actual sources.

Word has got a way to manually put in all sources or import them from a file. These options are both not ideal.

I've got the links that I need for each claim I make and can get an APA-style reference in text-format from Scribbr. Like the following:

```
De Backer, G. (2023, November 15). Cognitive Biases (2024): Complete list of 151 biases [Psychology]. Gust De Backer. https://gustdebacker.com/cognitive-biases/
```

However, I would need to manually fill in all required fields within Word or would need to import them all at once and remember where each source should be put in the text.

Been researching and testing all kinds of ways to automate this proces, but can't seem to be more efficient than only using shortcuts (ALT + L + A + B) and manually typing all fields for each source.

Curious if there are some smart people that can help me find ways to be more efficient ;-)

Comment: Does Scribbr let you export in a descriptive format, e.g. one with keywords and standardised separators, such as Title: "Cognitive Biases"; Year: 2024, that kind of thing. Much easier to deal with than trying to import something where your code has to parse the text.

Comment: Be aware that Word does not have built-in support for APA 7th. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/apa-7th-edition-word/0b54cbd8-fd3f-4b30-b94d-26802c1681e7